# Spring mvc interceptor addObject

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I have an interceptor which extends the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.

When I add an object to my `ModelAndView` it also gets added to my url as a path variable but I don't want that.

```
@Override
  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    if (null == modelAndView) {
      return;
    }

    log.info("Language in postHandle: {}", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    modelAndView.addObject("selectedLocale", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```

When I add something to my `ModelAndView` in the controller itself, it doesn't appear in the url.

Comment: I was wrong...I meant HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My suspicion is that the controller has returned a redirect view. When you add attributes to the model used by `RedirectView`, Spring will tack the attributes on to the URL.

Try looking inside the `ModelAndView` object to see if the view is a `RedirectView`, and if so, then don't add the locale attribute.

Comment: But i need the locale attribute? I use to give a different css style in my language menu option for the currently used language

Comment: @Villem: You're not understanding me.  Only add the attribute *if* the view is not a `RedirectView`.  Forwarding to a JSP is not a redirect, and that's where you need the attribute.

Comment: Where is this behavour of RecirectView described? I think its Javadoc should be updated.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
import static org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.REDIRECT_URL_PREFIX; 

private boolean isRedirectView(ModelAndView mv) {

    String viewName = mv.getViewName();
    if (viewName.startsWith(REDIRECT_URL_PREFIX)) {
        return true;
    }

    View view = mv.getView();
    return (view != null && view instanceof SmartView
            && ((SmartView) view).isRedirectView());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited the code and added a check if the is a RedirectView. If not than I will add the additional model objects.

```
@Override
  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
    if (null == modelAndView) {
      return;
    }

    log.info("Language in postHandle: {}", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

    if(!(modelAndView.getView() instanceof RedirectView)) {
      addAdditionalModelObjects(request, modelAndView);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used setAttribute on the request instead to get around this problem

```
request.setAttribute("jsFiles", children);
```