# ModelAndView Model objects not emptied on re-creation

Tags: spring, modelandview

My question is related to
[Spring mvc interceptor addObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786028/spring-mvc-interceptor-addobject)

At some point my application needs to know what the previousUrl is that has been visited, so in some occasions the previousUrl is stored in the ModelAndView and 'previous' can be called.

In another case I want to do a redirect and I don't want a previousUrl showing up in the URL bar of my browser. But when I try to initialize a new ModelAndView that old previousUrl object is still there. How is this possible?

The code

```
if (requestEmployee == null) {
    LOGGER.warn("User [" + requestEmployeeName + "] not found.");
    model = new ModelAndView(AbstractController.VIEW_REDIRECT_OVERVIEW, null);
    return model;
}
```

should create a new ModelAndView *without* model objects so why is the previousUrl object still added to the URL as path variable in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on what your handler method signature is.

Spring's `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` is actually adding model attributes from the returned `ModelAndView` [to the existing model attributes](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler.java#L78). If you have `Model` as one of your handler method argument and you are adding some attributes there, they will get merged.